# Make option to be notified about edit on post I downvoted

Tags: feature-request, edits, voting, down-votes, notifications

When one **downvotes** a question, he usually does so because **it is low quality**, but still **considerable** for the site (when it's not considerable, downvote should be avoided and question closed). It would be nice to have an ***option* to get notified when such a question is edited**; it likely means that it was improved and the downvoter might consider to revert his downvote.

The design could be something like this:

[image]

Where the `N` symbol would "lighten up in orange" like the arrows or the star do. (I'm not a designer and a letter is probably not a good option, but graphical design is not the matter now I hope.) The notification would be switched off automatically when the downvote is reverted (and the `N` button would disappear), and could be switched off manually of course.

The availability of such option just next to the downvote arrow would **encourage voters to return to the posts** they downvoted and **reconsider their vote**, and in the end, it would **encourage post owners to improve their posts** (because the chance of the downvotes being reversed would increase).

This might be used for answers as well, but they are surely not the primary concern.

Comment: So you want a notification on the post, but not in your inbox?

Comment: If this is an opt-in thing, and it drops into the inbox, I think it is great. Otherwise, I could really annoy some heavy question-downvoters by going through and cleaning up all the questions they downvoted.

Comment: @Bart If you mean whether "inbox" or "notifications": I'm not sure. I think that this might be ok in the notifications, but that is surely open to discussion.

Comment: @GeorgeWBush Surely opt-in, but suggestive by appearing directly under the downvote arrow. I thought about it for a good while to consider its pros and cons.

Comment: @Bart IMHO it should be the voter who decides whether he's notified, not the editor. Exactly as GWB explains, it can easily be annoying unless "completely opt-in".

Comment: @animuson why is this a dupe of that?  This one is for an option for the downvoter, that question is for the editor.

Comment: @lanceroberts ^^^