# Should SE/SO notify downvoters that the post has been edit?

Tags: discussion, voting

Should down voters be notified about your improvements? It seems like the who down votes your post will not come back and see what you have done.

**My Reasons**

For many new users like me, we do not automatically understand the the right approach to ask questions. (So we deserve to be down voted for that reason). But as we read and understand feedback from other experienced users, we can improve our post. But the down votes we received from previous newbie mistakes has already impacted us.

```
1. We are already in the verge of question ban after our first question.     
2. We risk to get question banned if we want to ask another question. 
3. Down voters who don't leave feed back does not allow new users to understand what is needed to be improved.
4. It would take some time for down voted post to gain some positive votes.
   //by that time, the answer you were seeking for is less valued.
```

As a [Simliar Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users) that has the simliar mindset.

Lastly, If your post is receiving many down votes with no reasoning, should you delete your post or continue revising and take the risk of losing asking question privileges?

Comment: The tooltip of the downvote button contains an explanation. No further comments are needed, specially when you're called all kind of nasty things if you try to leave a constructive comment. You might want to use the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and make sure you addressed all points before you post your question.

Comment: Deleting your post does not remove your risk of a question ban. While in most cases, deleting a post in itself does not count more towards the ban, it does not stop the post from counting towards a ban.

Comment: @Kendra If you keep receiving downvotes on your post, wouldn't you get question banned?

Comment: You can. It takes more than one downvoted post, however, and deleting a downvoted post will not stop those downvotes from counting against you. That's all I meant, sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @rene I personally think that if a down vote do not come with an explanation then it should not be down voted, instead down voters should just flag the question.

Comment: That's not what flags are for. And downvotes are never going to require an explicit explanation (see [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes))

Comment: Not all questions worthy of a downvote fall under one of the close reasons. A question can be low-quality or not useful (reasons to downvote) but not off-topic, too broad, opinion based, or a duplicate. You don't have to decide between one or the other.

Comment: I personally think down votes work fine to signal to posters that their question or answer needs work. As you responded to these down votes the system works.

Comment: worth reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes?rq=1 and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post) is the FR for notifying voters.

Comment: Relevant to your title question: [Option to be notified when a post I downvoted is edited](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247608/option-to-be-notified-when-a-post-i-downvoted-is-edited) (Your title and body are asking two different things but the answer to your title question is no)

Comment: Flag the question as what? None of the flags relate to "this is a poorly asked question". Hover over the downvote arrow on any site and read the tooltip... That's what downvotes are for.

Comment: Do you maybe have a link to the post you deleted so I can have a look and advice on the best way forward?

Comment: This post does deserve downvotes because you mangled three different thoughts into one so may as well vote down on the trend

Comment: @random Yes, they are 3 different thought but it revolves around the same topic.

Comment: @rene I decided not to delete the post and revise it instead. Here is my post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151345/how-can-you-split-a-list-to-another-list-if-it-contains-a-certain-value. Any advice on improvement is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Jackie kudos to you for striving to improve it and making that effort. Good luck with your programming :)

Comment: @Jackie here are some quick observations: Your question sounds similar as others, for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12172570), that could be part of the research that is now missing in the what you tried part. I'm unsure if all the Spring stuff with the controllers are needed to demo your actual issue. Try to make your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) self contained and copy-paste-runnable. I miss a short introduction with context, I wouldn't start-off with code. And I miss what your current code produces as output, so that it becomes clear what is exactly wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

Some quick answers to your title and body questions:

1. Downvoters (or upvoters) are not told when a post they have downvoted is edited.
2. If your revision truly improves the post, there should be no reason for it to garner more downvotes, unless there's foul play. Also, votes are locked after about five minutes. If you then edit, previous downvoters can reverse their votes. If you don't, they can't, until the post is edited.
3. I've deleted answers of mine that have been downvoted - even some with net positive scores - but only because the downvoters were absolutely right, and especially because there were much better answers than mine. I would not delete a post just to lose less rep points, but I would delete it if it was wrong.

   Question deletion is more complicated. As stated in [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/274942), deleted questions are taken into account for an automatic question ban. It's always better to improve posts than delete them. If I found myself in danger of a question ban, I'd just work on improving my current posts. Its possible that a post is so terrible that it can't be salvaged, but I tend to hope that that's only a very rare case.

Comment: Being able to delete downvoted posts is a privilege limited to those who have sufficient rep to not run into the question ban, which is, I think, one of this user's concerns. If they get a question ban, they will have to fix their questions in hopes of having the ban lifted.

Comment: @Catija It's not about having enough rep to not get question banned, rather, it's about learning from your mistakes and not *only* asking bad questions without ever improving.  Someone who asks a bad question, realizes what they did wrong, and from then on starts providing more positive contributions won't get banned.

Comment: @HDE226868 What if the question you asked is no longer needed? Eg; You found an alternative.

Comment: @Jackie If you found a solution, you could post it as an answer to your question. [Self-answering is encouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/274942) The knowledge could help other people, in the future.