# Add the ability to automatically follow a question on which I've added an answer or comment

Tags: feature-request, preferences, follow-post

If I offer an answer or add a comment to a question on Stack Overflow, I will invariably want to follow the question.

Have you ever considered adding a Settings option to do this automatically?

**EDIT:** Based on various responses let me make it clear that the Follow link should remain as-is and furthermore this has nothing to do with down-voting

**RELATED:**

[Ping commenters to write answers when a question is reopened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374491/578690) - a manual, time consuming workaround.

Comment: If I answer a question I have no need to follow it. If people want to respond to my answer there are the comments under my answer that will automatically give me a notification.

Comment: @Luuklag well, the request does say it's only with adding a setting, not default for all users.

Comment: If it were there instead of a "Follow" button, then I'd be toggling it on and off all the time which would get very irritating, I'd miss out on messages I wanted, and get loads that I didn't. It would be a very irritating facility. - If as well as the "Follow" button, then I don't see the point and would have it turned off all the time anyhow.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. As I understood the proposal, this would leave the follow button untouched, instead there would be a setting in your profile which would automatically press the follow button on all questions you comment on or answer

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Fair enough. I prefer to chose on a case by case basis. Your millage may vary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do question bookmarks work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-question-bookmarks-work)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implicitly start following by downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359937/282094)

Comment: @Rob It's related, but I wouldn't say it's a duplicate. This question is about answers and comments and the other one is about downvotes. Also the other one wants the proposed feature to apply to everybody, but this one just wants a setting to be available for those who want.

Comment: There are users who have posted thousands and tens of thousands of answers in ten or more years. I'm pretty sure they would hate the proposed automatic setting.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There was no suggestion to make this automatic! The post suggests an option! If somebody has so many posts, they don't have to activate this option.

Comment: @Rob How does an answer about downvoting and moving on answer a question about following an interesting post which you commended/answered, which makes it likely that you care about the topic?

Comment: @sam read the answer, > "To align with this behavior, following a post you voted on shouldn't be implicit - if you want to follow it, it's just one click away.

Having said that, I'm sure that the SE engineers have a way of pulling ...". - Middle of something important.

Comment: @Rob Answering/commenting is very different than downvoting. It is understandable that SE wants users to move on when they downvote - much less drama to be caused this way. However if a user is obviously interested in a subject, why not make it easier for them to follow a post?

Comment: sam & Don,  the answer explains that auto-following (for whatever reason) would (likely) be best if it were opt-in - you are splitting the difference between going back and forth from your settings to set / unset the setting for each possible reason and simply clicking follow on the question or answer itself. [continued]

Comment: sam & Donald --- If people would choose to leave the setting either on or off and not go back and forth then having such a setting makes sense; and that answer explains how such decisions are reached - neither of you took issue with [Rock Ape's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372233/add-the-ability-to-automatically-follow-a-question-on-which-ive-added-an-answer#comment1243278_372233).

Answer (score 10):

I would love to have such an option! I also forget to follow posts I commented/answered, but I would like to follow them because:

- if I answer a post, I would like to get notified if other answers get posted so I can check if there are any new tricks to learn I did not yet know
- if I comment below a question it is usually to ask for more information. Obviously I'd like to know if the posts get edited to add the missing information so I can try to answer the problem

I understand that this option would not be useful for everybody, but that's why this feature request proposes an setting to **optionally** switch on the auto-following and not make this default.