# Ping commenters to write answers when a question is reopened

Tags: discussion, comments, chat, vote-to-reopen, ping

My question was closed. While closed, it accumulated comments from people who could potentially answer, not just comment. After reopening, I wrote a very brief comment to each person, inviting them to answer if they are still interested. I pinged (at-mentioned) each person, with 1 comment per person to ensure that each one is pinged exactly once.

Should I use the per-site Chat instead?

What is the accepted method in such cases?

**NOTES:**

[Add the ability to automatically follow a question on which I've added an answer or comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372233/578690) - This automatic method would have been a great replacement for the manual, time-consuming method discussed in my post, above.

**SEE ALSO:**

[How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/578690)
[How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415/578690)
[Edited-and-Reopened Questions Should Ping Downvoters](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19369/839429)

Comment: The pinging method worked for me on Politics.SE for [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/70052/28554) rather well. Now asking about more general (Stack Exchange) conventions.

Comment: If for example a user asked you to incluse aditional data in your question pinging them to notify you did is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Luuklag Agreed. Also, some comments look like mini answers. I pinged those commenters too. Hope that’s OK.

Comment: Yeah thats usually fine @Timur

Comment: This problem would not exists if we could automatically follow posts on which we commented https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372244/237989

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Now this is the perfect answer to my question! Yes!

Comment: @TimurShtatland Maybe you could add an answer to the post I linked to? From the perspective of a post author who faces the dilemma to either spam people who don't want to be notified or to miss good answers because users don't notice a post was reopened?

Comment: What's wrong with the 'follow' option? If they're interested enough, they can bookmark or follow your question to keep an eye on it. I'm not sure pinging like this is going to be appreciated by all commenters.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for the suggestion! I added the cross link between the two posts.